# In Ethereum, how do I interface with a contract on the blockchain?

Tags: ethereum

When I publish a *new* contract using the output of a compiler, I get a javascript object "somecontract" which I can call methods on like so: "somecontract.doSomething();"

But how do I interact with a contract that was published to the blockchain at some point in the past?

Answer (score 7):

If you already have the contract address skip to the code snippet below. If not, you’ll need to find it.

1. Look up the account the contract was published from on etherchain.org
2. Find the transaction you used to create the contract. It’ll be one of the “new contract” rows.
3. Finally, inside geth, get the transaction receipt, and the contract address will be the “contractAddress” property of the receipt.

To get the abi, recompile your contract (usually here https://chriseth.github.io/browser-solidity/). Now that you have the abi and the contract address, you’re ready to regain access to the contract.

```
var abi = <cut and paste the contract abi here>;
var contract = web3.eth.contract(abi).at(<contract address>);
contract.functionname();
contract.functionname.sendTransaction(...);
```

This is a sample abi from https://github.com/fivedogit/solidity-baby-steps/blob/master/contracts/05_greeter.sol

```
[{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"kill","outputs":[],"type":"function"},
    {"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getBlockNumber","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},
    {"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_newgreeting","type":"string"}],"name":"setGreeting","outputs":[],"type":"function"},
    {"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"greet","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"name":"_greeting","type":"string"}],"type":"constructor"}]
```